# Building array from awk output

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, awk, cat

Can anyone explain why the following doesn't work please?

list

```
the letter is d
the number is 4
the number is 2
the letter is g
```

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

cat "$1" | grep letter | array=($(awk '{print $4}'))

for i in "${array[@]}"
do
  :
  echo $i
done
```

If I run this `bash script.sh list` I expect the array to print d and g, but it doesn't. I think its because of how I am trying to set the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think its because of how I am trying to set the array.

Each command in a pipeline `|` is run in a subshell - as a separate process. The parent process does not "see" variable changes from a child process.

Just:

```
array=($(grep letter "$1" | awk '{print $4}'))
```

or

```
array=($(awk '/letter/{print $4}' "$1"))
```

Run variable assignment in the parent shell.

Comment: Ah ok thanks. I used the top one but you missed a ")". Works great.

Answer (score 1):

You should assign the complete row of piped commands to a variable.

```
array=($(cat "$1" | grep letter | awk '{print $4}'))
```

The `cat` and `grep` command can be combined with `awk`, but why do you want an array?
I think you want the process each element in one loop, so first remove the double quotes:

```
for i in ${array[@]}
do
  :
  echo $i
done
```

Next, try to do this without an array

```
while read -r i; do
  :
  echo $i
done < <(awk '/letter/ {print $4}' "$1")
```

Comment: You are so right. I wanted to do so, but I started with copying the question. Corrected.